# Rendering CIImage results in a blank image on macOS 10.15.7 (19H1030)

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, core-image

After installing the Security Update 2021-002 Catalina, rendering a Core Image image stopped working properly.
The code below results in a blank image:

```
    let ciContext = CIContext(options: [.useSoftwareRenderer: true])
    guard let srcPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Flowers", ofType: "jpg"),
        let ciImage = CIImage(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: srcPath)) else { return }
    let dstUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSString("~/Desktop/1.jpg").expandingTildeInPath)
    guard let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(dstUrl as CFURL, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, nil) else { return }
    guard let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else { return }
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, cgImage, nil)
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
```

The following error is printed to the console:

```
** OpenCL Error Notification: [CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE] : OpenCL Error : Error: build program driver returned (-1) **
** OpenCL Error Notification: OpenCL Warning : clBuildProgram failed: could not build program for 0xffffffff (Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8500B CPU @ 3.00GHz) (err:-1) ** Native OpenCL program build failed:
```

The temporary solution to fix this issue is to disable software rendering by setting the **useSoftwareRenderer** option to false when creating a CIContext.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Catalina Security Update 2021-002 breaks OpenCL. clBuildProgram always fails with a CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE, even with basic kernels, and clGetProgramBuildInfo returns an empty string, not providing any clue what's wrong. The security update release notes don't mention OpenCL at all, but this regression is directly caused by it. The corresponding Security Update for Mojave does not have this regression, and neither does Big Sur 10.3. Only on Catalina it is broken now. Filed a bug report. Please do so as well.

Comment: @S--, thanks for your reply. I have also filed a bug report.

Comment: @S--, fixed in macOS Catalina Security Update Developer Beta 2021-003.